# terraform overwrite tag value in sub modules

Tags: tags, terraform, terraform-modules

I'm using terraform modules and passing a set of default_tags to sub-modules for consistent tagging. This is shown below, and has the advantage that sub-modules inherit their parent's tags, but can also add their own.

However what I'd also like to do is to be able to overwrite some of the inherited tags values, especially "Name". But I can't seem to make this work.

In the example below (terraform 13.5 with AWS) the first value specified for any tag, e.g. "scratch-test" in the root module is cascaded down to the sub-modules, and cannot be changed. So both the VPC Name tag and the subnet Name tag = "scratch-test".

**How can I overwrite a tag value in a sub-module?**

```
# root variables.tf
variable "default_tags" {
    type = map
    default = {
        environment_type = "Dev Environment"
    }
} 


# root main.tf
provider "aws" {
    region = var.region
}

module "vpc" {
    source = "../../../../scratch/tags-pattern"
    vpc_name                = "scratch-test"
    public_subnets          = ["10.0.0.0/26"]

    default_tags = merge(map(
        "Name", "scratch-test"
    ), var.default_tags)
}
```

```
# ../../../../scratch/tags-pattern/main.tf
module "the_vpc" {
    source = "../../terraform/tf-lib/network/vpc"

    vpc_name = var.vpc_name
    vpc_cidr = "10.0.0.0/24"

    default_tags = merge(map(
        "Name", "scratch-test-vpc",
        "vpc_tag", "vpc"
    ), var.default_tags)
}

# Add a subnet
module "public_subnets" {
    source = "../../terraform/tf-lib/network/subnet"
    vpc_id                  = module.the_vpc.output_vpc_id
    subnets                 = var.public_subnets
    default_tags = merge(map(
        "Name", "scratch-test-subnet",
        "subnet_tag", "public"
    ), var.default_tags)
}
```

```
# tf-lib/network/vpc/main.tf
resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
    cidr_block = var.vpc_cidr
    enable_dns_support = true
    enable_dns_hostnames = true
    tags = merge(map(
        "module", "tf-lib/network/vpc"
    ), var.default_tags)
}
```

The variable.tf file for each module contains the statement:

```
variable "default_tags" {}
```

Comment: You should look at aws provider `default_tags` block too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`merge` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/merge.html) sets precedence by overwriting with the latter maps defined in the argument sequence:

> `merge` takes an arbitrary number of maps or objects, and returns a single map or object that contains a merged set of elements from all arguments.
>
> If more than one given map or object defines the same key or attribute, then the one that is later in the argument sequence takes precedence. If the argument types do not match, the resulting type will be an object matching the type structure of the attributes after the merging rules have been applied.

So to allow for you to override the default tags you can specify the default tags first like this:

```
# root variables.tf
variable "default_tags" {
    type = map
    default = {
        environment_type = "Dev Environment"
    }
} 


# root main.tf
provider "aws" {
    region = var.region
}

module "vpc" {
    source = "../../../../scratch/tags-pattern"
    vpc_name                = "scratch-test"
    public_subnets          = ["10.0.0.0/26"]

    default_tags = merge(var.default_tags, map(
        "Name", "scratch-test"
    ))
}
```

The above might also look clearer using the `{}` map syntax rather than the [`map` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/map.html) too:

```
# root main.tf
provider "aws" {
    region = var.region
}

module "vpc" {
    source = "../../../../scratch/tags-pattern"
    vpc_name                = "scratch-test"
    public_subnets          = ["10.0.0.0/26"]

    default_tags = merge(var.default_tags, {
      Name = "scratch-test",
    })
}
```

As mentioned in the `map` function documentation this function is deprecated and will eventually be removed:

> **This function is deprecated.** From Terraform v0.12, the Terraform
> language has built-in syntax for creating maps using the `{` and `}`
> delimiters. Use the built-in syntax instead. The `map` function will be
> removed in a future version of Terraform.

Comment: Thanks, that is great, and you can still add further tags too!

Answer (score 1):

As of [AWS Provider v3.38.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/v3.38.0/CHANGELOG.md), this can be done more simply. See [this announcement blog](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/default-tags-in-the-terraform-aws-provider). Here is your request implemented with the new provider and no `tags` variables.

```
# root main.tf
provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
  default_tags {
    tags = {
      environment_type = "Dev Environment"
    }
  }
}

module "vpc" {
  source         = "../../../../scratch/tags-pattern"
  vpc_name       = "scratch-test"
  public_subnets = ["10.0.0.0/26"]
}

# ../../../../scratch/tags-pattern/main.tf
module "the_vpc" {
  source = "../../terraform/tf-lib/network/vpc"

  vpc_name = var.vpc_name
  vpc_cidr = "10.0.0.0/24"

}

# tf-lib/network/vpc/main.tf
resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  cidr_block           = var.vpc_cidr
  enable_dns_support   = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true

  tags = {
    Name    = "scratch-test-vpc"
    module  = "tf-lib/network/vpc"
    vpc_tag = "vpc"
  }
}
```

Here is the [main documentation for default_tags](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#default_tags-configuration-block).